# How to get Google calendar to display in native website language, not by IP address?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

[image]I want to Embed a google calendar on my website.

Problem is, visitors see it displayed in the country's language...

If you are in Thailand, calendar shows up in Thai, if in France French etc...

However, I want the calendar to display in English no matter the IP address of the visitor...

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `&hl=ca` at the end of the iframe link.

Add your custom "*locale*". In my case catalan=`ca` and for english=`en`.

Hope this can help other people searching the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the back end of Google calendar, select English as calendar language...that's it;)